# API C++ para editar modelos tridimensionales

Tags: c++, motor-de-juego, unreal-engine

Les comento que estamos desarrollando un proyecto de visualización arquitectónica utilizando el motor de videojuegos Unreal Engine. Tenemos un requerimiento que se nos viene complicando mucho para completar a partir de las herramientas que brinda Unreal Engine, y es cambiar los colores de cada polígono del modelo individualmente, recibiendo la lista de colores por parámetro.

Como este motor admite la programación con C++ (complementando a su propio lenguaje gráfico llamado Blueprints), quisiera saber si hay alguna API que pueda integrar al proyecto C++ y que permita la edición de modelos, particularmente con formatos .obj y/o .fbx, en el que se pueda acceder al bajo nivel del modelo y editar el color individualmente a cada polígono.

Edit: Sería bueno que dicha API permita generar un archivo nuevo para el modelo con los cambios realizados, para entonces poder separar lo que es esta edición a bajo nivel del modelo y el resto del procesamiento en el Unreal Engine.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problema solucionado desde Unreal Engine**

Encontramos la solución para pintar los polígonos desde Unreal Engine y la posteo por si alguien está con el mismo problema. La idea de la solución es asignar una instancia dinámica del material a cada polígono del modelo, partiendo de un material base con un parámetro en el color de base. Para cada instancia dinámica del material se deberá asignar el color de base para darle color a los polígonos. La asignación de colores debe hacerse en el PostInitializeComponents. En este caso de ejemplo se asigna solo un nuevo color a muchos polígonos, pero podría setearse un color por cara de la misma forma, realizando esta asignación dentro del loop.

Definición del material (creado en el editor):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Modelo.h:**

```
    UCLASS()
class BOTONLUZ_API AModelo : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AModelo();

    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

    virtual void PostInitializeComponents() override;

    UPROPERTY(Category = StaticMeshActor, VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly,
        Meta = (ExposeFunctionCategories = "Mesh,Rendering,Physics,Components|StaticMesh", AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
        UStaticMeshComponent * modeloActor;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Materials)
        UMaterial* BaseMat;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Materials)
        UMaterialInstanceDynamic* MaterialInst;

    bool errorCargaModelo;

};
```

**Modelo.cpp:**

```
    AModelo::AModelo()
{

    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    errorCargaModelo = false;

    // Carga del material
    static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UMaterial> MatObj(TEXT("Material'/Game/Materiales/MaterialEjemplo.MaterialEjemplo'"));
    if (MatObj.Succeeded()){
        BaseMat = MatObj.Object;
    }

    static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh> cargadorModelo(TEXT("/Game/Modelos/basico_mm"));
    UStaticMesh* modelo;
    if (cargadorModelo.Succeeded()){
        modelo = cargadorModelo.Object;
    }
    else {
        errorCargaModelo = true;
        return;
    }

    if (!modelo->IsValidLowLevel()){
        errorCargaModelo = true;
        return;
    }
    if (&modelo->SourceModels[0] == nullptr){
        errorCargaModelo = true;
        return;
    }

    FStaticMeshSourceModel* sourceModel = &modelo->SourceModels[0];
    FRawMesh rawMesh;
    sourceModel->RawMeshBulkData->LoadRawMesh(rawMesh);

    for (int32 i = 0; i < rawMesh.FaceMaterialIndices.Num(); i++){
        rawMesh.FaceMaterialIndices[i] = i;
    }

    // Creo nuevo modelo
    UStaticMesh* modeloNuevo = NewObject<UStaticMesh>();
    new(modeloNuevo->SourceModels) FStaticMeshSourceModel();
    modeloNuevo->SourceModels[0].RawMeshBulkData->SaveRawMesh(rawMesh);

    for (int32 i = 0; i < rawMesh.FaceMaterialIndices.Num(); i++){
        modeloNuevo->Materials.Add(BaseMat);
    }

    TArray<FText> BuildErrorsNuevo;
    modeloNuevo->Build(true, &BuildErrorsNuevo);
    modeloNuevo->MarkPackageDirty();

    // Asigno nuevo modelo
    modeloActor = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("ModeloActor"));
    modeloActor->SetStaticMesh(modeloNuevo);
}

    void AModelo::PostInitializeComponents()
    {
        Super::PostInitializeComponents();
        if (!errorCargaModelo){
            if (BaseMat)
            {
                // Creo y agrego materiales a la lista del modelo
                MaterialInst = UMaterialInstanceDynamic::Create(BaseMat, this);
                modeloActor->SetMaterial(0, MaterialInst);
                FLinearColor color1 = FLinearColor::Yellow;
                MaterialInst->SetVectorParameterValue("baseColor", color1);

                for (int32 i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    modeloActor->SetMaterial(i, MaterialInst);
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Luego de hacer spawn del actor desde un blueprint, el modelo queda pintado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que les sirva.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo no he usado tanto Unreal Engine para tener que usar HLSL, pero si lo toque un poco en XNA

Mira si puedes lograrlo

- https://wiki.unrealengine.com/HLSL_Shaders
- https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?69433-Colored-vignette

Answer (score 0):

Para desarrollo de CAD puedes probar con [OpenCascade](http://www.opencascade.com). Es un motor bastante bueno y está especializado en diseño CAD y modelado 3D, lo que creo que se adecua bastante a tus necesidades.